# Set Notes from Column A based on contents of Column B

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I found this short script that takes the contents of cell B1 and sets it as the comment/note of cell A1.  Id like to run this for all rows, not just row #1 (or more specifically rows 4-100).  How can this be scripted?

```
    function addNote() {
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
      var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
      var targetCell = sheet.getRange("A1");
      var sourceCell = sheet.getRange("B1");
    
      var noteText = sourceCell.getValue();
    
      targetCell.setNote(noteText);
}
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function addNote() {
  var ss           = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet        = ss.getSheets()[0];
  var values_range = sheet.getRange("A4:A100");
  var notes_range  = sheet.getRange("B4:B100");
  var notes        = notes_range.getValues();

  values_range.setNotes(notes)
}
```

#### Refernce

- [setNotes(notes)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range.html#setNotes(Object))
- [getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range.html#getValues())

Answer (score 0):

You may using the following code, which will perform the loop for `400 row` as you preferred:

```
function addNote() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
      for (var i = 1;i<=400;i++){
        var targetCell = sheet.getRange(i,1);
        var sourceCell = sheet.getRange(i,2);
        var noteText = sourceCell.getValue();
        targetCell.setNote(noteText);
      }     
}
```

Comment: Well, it does work. But... 800 gets + 400 sets. it takes about 2 minutes to finish. And it can exceed the limit for requests to the server. I strongly encourage to use `getValues()` and `setNotes()` instead.

Comment: @YuriKhristich, good to know there is faster method, thanks