# Converting Formula Result in cell into Notes

Tags: google-apps-script

So I understand this is very similar to:
[Set Notes from Column A based on contents of Column B](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67859448/set-notes-from-column-a-based-on-contents-of-column-b)

```
    function addNote() {
      var ss           = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
      var sheet        = ss.getSheets()[0];
      var values_range = sheet.getRange("R5:R6");
      var notes_range  = sheet.getRange("AS5:AS6");
      var notes        = notes_range.getValues();

      values_range.setNotes(notes)
    }
```

However it's returning blank for me. It seems to be because the cells are the results of a SUM.
Is there a way to get the result?

Comment: SUM of what...? Any Google finance formulae?

Comment: I have 2 numerical values in cells R5 and AM5.
In cell AS5 I calculate the difference between them i.e: =SUM(R5-AM5)

Comment: What does your sum have to do with column A & B?

Comment: Sorry both, I had pasted the code from the link. I will edit my post.

Comment: After further testing, I found that it's nothing to do with the calculation but the fact it was running on the first tab. Now i'll go look for a way to make it run on tab 2 onwards

Answer (score 0):

#### Copy display values in column B as notes in column A

```
function addNote() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0")
  const vs = sh.getRange(2,2,sh.getLastRow() - 1).getDisplayValues();
  vs.forEach((r,i)=>{
    sh.getRange(i + 2,1).setNote(r[0])
  });
}
```